# Script works inconsistently

Tags: python

I'm importing 300-400 images via *Images as planes* add-on, stacking them at world origin and below each other (0.001 offset). Render engine is *Blender Internal*. Then I want to disable interpolation for all textures with this small code:

```
import bpy

for x in bpy.data.textures:
    x.use_interpolation = False
```

**Sometimes it works**, especially for amounts of images less than 10-20, but usually it throws **error:**

> AttributeError: 'Texture' object has no attribute
>   'use_interpolation'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Non blender internal textures**

There may be some textures in blend that don't have the `use_interpolation` property.  For example switch to cycles and add a new brush texture.  `bpy.data.textures["Texture"]` the newly added one, doesn't.

Check whether the texture has the attribute with `hasattr`

```
>>> for t in bpy.data.textures:
...     t.name, hasattr(t, "use_interpolation")
...     
('dice', True)
('Tex', True)
('Texture', False)
```

Find all with that property, then set.

```
bi_textures = [t for t in bpy.data.textures if hasattr(t, "use_interpolation")]
for t in bi_textures:
    t.use_interpolation = False
```

or get the textures from the materials on the planes. Test code to get all textures on selected nesh objects

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

textures = [ts.texture 
        for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH'
        for m in o.data.materials 
        for ts in m.texture_slots if ts and ts.texture]
```